# sending request with json to php server in android

Tags: php, android, json

hi to all i am new to android i have to send my different data using json to php server like 
Tag----- student details
student ----- n object which is having details of each students
like student 1
name
id 
dob
class 
roll no
student 2
.
.
.
..
student n

tag ------ teacher details
teacher---------- n objects which are having details of each teacher
like 
teacher name
teacher id
doj
designation

i have tried using creating name value pair list first value pair was tag -- student/teacher
other value pair i was creating using json object --> json array-->json object (name value pair)-->details of teache/student
any help or sample code will be appritiated .... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this function to post the name-value pair to a php script

```
public void postData(List nameValuePairs){  
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        String url = "http://localhost/recieve.php";
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            // Add your data
            //List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(1);
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(a, b));
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Number", b));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
```

to post the data use ->

```
List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Number", b))
postData(nameValuePairs);
```

Hope this helps.

Sample Code ->

```
package com.mypackage;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import com.loopj.android.http.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.NetworkInfo.State;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MypackageActivity extends Activity {

    //SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
      }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           startr();


    }



    public void startr() {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Onstart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");   
        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        imei = manager.getDeviceId();
        List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imeiimsi", imei+imsi));
        postData(nameValuePairs, "sms");
        nameValuePairs.clear();
        // Set looping  
        }   





    public void postData(List nameValuePairs){  
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        url = "http://localhost/logs.php";
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //need to change it when run on phn :P :P
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            // Add your data
            //List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(1);
            //for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(a, b));
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Number", b));


                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    } 
}
```

Make a new Project name it myproject, then create an activity class and see the sample code above !

Comment: can you send me full sample code as i told you i am a beginner